# Python: 2D Numpy Array (Matrix) - Finding Sum of Negative Numbers (Rows)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix (using `numpy`), user enters number of rows and columns. After going through some FOR loops, user enters elements, of course depending on what number of rows and columns did he/she has chosen.

Now I need to find a sum of negative elements for every row below row 7 and output this every row sum, right after the exact row. Here is my code (even though code for this last thing doesn't work)

```
import numpy as np
A = list()
n = int(input("How many rows: "))
m = int(input("How many columns: "))

for x in range(n):
    if n <= 0 or n>10:
         print("Out of range")
         break
    elif m <= 0 or m>10:
         print("Out of range")
         break
    else:
        for y in range(m):
             num = input("Element: ")
             A.append(int(num))

shape = np.reshape(A,(n,m))

for e in range(n < 7):
    if e < 0:
        print(sum(e))

print(shape)
```

If as a user, I will enter 3 rows and 3 columns, I can get something like this (I'll enter some numbers to explain what I need):

```
[-1, 2, -3]
[-4, 5, -6]
[-7, -8, 9]
```

I should get something like this:

```
[-1, 2, -3] Sum of Negative Elements In This Row (Till 7th) [-4]
[-4, 5, -6] Sum of Negative Elements In This Row (Till 7th) [-10]
[-7, -8, 9] Sum of Negative Elements In This Row (Till 7th) [-15]
```

Also please don't forget I need it only till row 7, even if it will have more rows, I am not interested in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through every row of your 2D array and select the negative values with `row[row < 0]` and calculate the sum of these values:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[-1, 2, -3], [-4, 5, -6], [-7, -8, 9]])  # your array

for row in a:
    neg_sum = sum(row[row < 0])  # sum of negative values
    print('{} Sum of Negative Elements In This Row: {}'.format(row, neg_sum))
```

This prints:

```
[-1  2 -3] Sum of Negative Elements In This Row: -4
[-4  5 -6] Sum of Negative Elements In This Row: -10
[-7 -8  9] Sum of Negative Elements In This Row: -15
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is exactly what i needed.

Comment: One question, if i add [:7,:] to for row in a: it will cut down everything even if matrix is 8x8, how can i manage to show whole matrix, but calculate negative numbers till 7th ?

Comment: Keep the full row (`for row in a`) but include this into the `neg_sum = ...` line.

Comment: So i need to add [:7,:] not to( `for row in a` ) , but to ( `neg_sum = line` ) ? 
I really don't know where to add, it gives me error that dimension is 8 and i have till 7, but no result

Answer (score 1):

```
a = np.random.random_integers(-1, 1, (10,3))
>>> a
array([[ 0,  0, -1],
       [ 1, -1, -1],
       [ 0,  1,  1],
       [-1,  0,  0],
       [ 1, -1,  0],
       [-1,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  0],
       [ 1, -1,  0],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [ 1, -1,  1]])
>>>
```

You can slice a numpy array in any of its dimensions. The first seven rows would be:

```
>>> a[:7,:]
array([[ 0,  0, -1],
       [ 1, -1, -1],
       [ 0,  1,  1],
       [-1,  0,  0],
       [ 1, -1,  0],
       [-1,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  0]])
>>>
```

Iterating over the array produces rows which can be summed. Boolean indexing can be used to select items based on a condition:

```
>>> for row in a[:7,:]:
...     less_than_zero = row[row < 0]
...     sum_less_than = np.sum(less_than_zero)
...     print('row:{:<14}\tless than zero:{:<11}\tsum:{}'.format(row, less_than_zero, sum_less_than))


row:[ 0  0 -1]      less than zero:[-1]         sum:-1
row:[ 1 -1 -1]      less than zero:[-1 -1]      sum:-2
row:[0 1 1]         less than zero:[]           sum:0
row:[-1  0  0]      less than zero:[-1]         sum:-1
row:[ 1 -1  0]      less than zero:[-1]         sum:-1
row:[-1  1  1]      less than zero:[-1]         sum:-1
row:[0 1 0]         less than zero:[]           sum:0
>>>
```